# The argument type 'bool' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Bool'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner in flutter

I try to get the boolean value from the Future< bool> type function

And this my Dart language coding file

I get following error from 38th line

CODE//

QuestionA q1=QuestionA(q:'Sharks are mammals', a: true );

Full code `your t

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'qaa.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(myApp());
}

class myApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const myApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        body: quizzler(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class quizzler extends StatefulWidget {
  const quizzler({super.key});


  @override
  State<quizzler> createState() => _quizzlerState();
}
class _quizzlerState extends State<quizzler> {
  late String q;
  late bool a;
  List<String> questions=[
    'Sharks are mammals',
    'Sea otters have a favorite rock they use to break open food.',
    'the blue whale is the biggest animal to have ever lived.'
  ];
  QuestionA q1=QuestionA(q:'Sharks are mammals', a: true );
  List<bool>answers=[false,
    true,
    true];
  List<Icon>checkedbox=[];
  int quesnum=0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                questions[quesnum],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.white
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                bool Correctans=answers[quesnum];
                if(Correctans==true)
                {
                  checkedbox.add(Icon(Icons.check,color: Colors.green,));
                }
                else
                {
                  checkedbox.add(Icon(Icons.close,color: Colors.red,));
                }
                quesnum=quesnum+1;
                if(quesnum==3)
                {
                  quesnum=0;
                }
              });
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Center(child: Text('True',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                ),
                height: 100,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex:1,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  bool falseans=answers[quesnum];
                  if(falseans==false)
                  {
                    checkedbox.add(Icon(Icons.check,color: Colors.green,));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    checkedbox.add(Icon(Icons.close,color: Colors.red,));
                  }
                  quesnum=quesnum+1;
                  if(quesnum==3)
                  {
                    quesnum=0;
                  }
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 100,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('False',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                    ),),
                ),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            ...checkedbox,
          ],)
        ],
      ),);
  }
}
```

ext`
I have also imported the class that i created in the another folder

```
import 'dart:ffi';

class QuestionA{
    late String questions;
     late Bool answers;

    QuestionA({ required String q, required Bool a}){
        questions=q;
        answers=a;
    }

}
```

The argument type 'bool' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Bool'. help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change Bool to bool in your model class

```dart
import 'dart:ffi'; // remove this import

class QuestionA{
    late String questions;
     late bool answers; // its bool not Bool

    QuestionA({ required String q, required bool a}){
        questions=q;
        answers=a;
    }
}
```